# extract specific rows of .tbl files in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with the following links:

[image: .xlsx file]

These links are connected to files with the following data:

[image: .tbl file]

I want the yellow part of the notepad file to be read into the .xlsx file yellow parts (the notepad is an opened version of the .tbl file). The dotted parts differ for each Version number. (This code is used as a check that the right discount curve is used). However, the discount_curve.tbl format is the only format the next programme used is able to handle. Therefore, it has the same name just in a different folder.

Is there a way excel/vba can read in every third line whilst the file read in depends on the folder link? I strongly prefer to have the whole process automated since there are many many version numbers. Furthermore, I do not want to change the file formatting, since I want the process to be as clean as possible.

Could someone help me out?
Kind regards.

Comment: What is your problem? Concatenate the cells of on row to get the filename? Open a Textfile? Read the textfile row by row? Finding the correct line? Write the result into a cell? Nothing of the tasks is difficult and you will for sure find a lot of answers here on SO and elsewhere

Comment: My specific problem is in reading the third lines of the .tbl files to that excel cell.

Comment: I can see a "Data" line, after the yellow one... Is it part of the txt file? I mean, is the yellow line firstly the third one, but after that the fourth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for common I/O opearations i.e. reading file line by line.
Pretty good example was shown [here][1]

To reach your goal we need to add some if-conditions to extract every third line of your text files.
Modulo division will be a good helper.
For example we have 'i' as row number
then we just need to make an if condition looks smth like that:

```
If (i mod 3) = 0 Then ...
```

It means that we're looking for every 'i' which divided by 3 gives us a remainder of 0
This way our code will look something like this

```
Sub ReadFileLineByLine()
Dim my_file As Integer
Dim text_line As String
Dim file_name As String
Dim i As Integer   

file_name = "C:\text_file.txt"   

my_file = FreeFile()
Open file_name For Input As my_file   

i = 1   

While Not EOF(my_file)
    Line Input #my_file, text_line
    If (i mod 3) = 0 Then
        Cells(i, "A").Value = text_line
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

End Sub

[1]: https://excel.officetuts.net/vba/read-a-text-file/#:~:text=Reading%20a%20file%20line%20by%20line,-Let's%20read%20text&text=Open%20VBA%20Edit%20(Alt%20%2B%20F11,and%20insert%20the%20following%20code.&text=First%2C%20a%20new%20file%20is,places%20it%20inside%20a%20worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

Please, try the next function, if the necessary data to be extracted exists **in a single file, at every three rows**.. It will return a 2D array able to be dropped at once in the range you need:

```
Function extractThirdLine(filePath As String) As Variant
     Dim arrTxt, i As Long, arrFin, k As Long
     'read the file content in an array:
     arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filePath, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
     ReDim arrFin(1 To Int(UBound(arrTxt) / 3) + 1, 1 To 1)
     For i = 2 To UBound(arrTxt) Step 3 'start from 2, because  arrTxt is 1D array
        k = k + 1
        arrFin(k, 1) = arrTxt(i) 'build the filal array containing the necessary rows
     Next i
     extractThirdLine = arrFin
End Function
```

Your picture does not show the rows and columns headers. So, supposing that the range you show us exists in columns "A:C" and you need to place the extracted data in column "D:D", please use the next way:

```
Sub testExtractThirdLine()
   Dim filePath As String, arrVal, el
   filePath = "your text file full name" 'please write here the correct file  name
   arrVal = extractThirdLine(filePath)
   Range("D1").Resize(UBound(arrVal), 1).value = arrVal
End Sub
```

If the range you show is not the one I supposed, you cam easily adapt `Range("D1")` to the immediately after the columns range and its row to be the first row of the range in discussion.

If something not clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

**Edited**:

But if each third line can be found in a file, for each row, and the path to the respective file is obtained by concatenation of the three columns, the next function will do the job:

```
Function extractLine(filePath As String) As String
   extractLine = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(filePath, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)(2)
End Function
```

It can be called as:

```
Sub extractStrings()
 Dim i As Long, arr, arrFin, lastRow As Long
 
 lastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'supposing that 'C:\' exists in A:A column
 arr = Range("A2:C" & lastRow).value
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    arrFin(i, 1) = extractLine(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3))
 Next i
 'drop the processed array content at once:
 Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the OP need the third line off each file, and not every third line of one file

Comment: @Vincent G Ups...! Reading again, it looks you are right. In such a case the function can return with only a code line. I will post another function, only for the sake of playing with VBA... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a User function that will read the lines from the given file and return the third one.

Here is such a function (Disclaimer: there is no error management in this code it can probably be improved a lot)

```
Function Get3rdLine(filename As String)
    Dim f As Long
    f = FreeFile
    Open filename For Input As f
    Line Input #f, Get3rdLine ' just ignore this line
    Line Input #f, Get3rdLine ' and this one too
    Line Input #f, Get3rdLine ' and return this one
    Close #f
End Function
```

You can call it with the path of the file you want to read from:

`=Get3rdLine(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1))` for example if your path is defined by cells A1, B1 and C1.